# How can I put a button next to each other in Laravel 6.0 using bootstrap? I tried but it is still one up and other down

Tags: html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

***This is how I tried, I want to see them next to each other***

- Below i put my css i tried with form-inline and it didn't work also tried with display:inline but it didn't work

`Code of the button`

```html
                <td>
                    <div class="container ">
                       <a href="/miembros/{{$item->id_miembro}}/correos" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">Ver</a>
                       <a href="/correos/create" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">Agregar</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
```

***This is my css***

```css
<style>
          body {
                padding-top: 56px;
          background-image: url("/fondoevento.jpg");
          background-size: cover;
            }

      .dropnegro{
  color: #141519;
  text-align: center;

       }
      nav.navbar {
            background: #141519;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #424448, #B7BCCD);
        }
        .tamano{
          font-size: 16px;
        }
        .tope{
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        .centro{
            text-align: center;
        }
        .in{
            display: inline;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: You are going to have to provide more info, we need the CSS declarations of all the styles you are using. My guess would be that the width of the TD isn't allowing the link to show next to the other one. If you set the width to some length long enough to show both links side by side it should work.

Comment: The width change the size but still doesn't work,i put the css code above

Comment: I am asking about the classes: container, btn, btn-dark, btn-sm.

Comment: `container btn btn-dark btn-sm` are all governed by Bootstrap _ The code that would probably be useful is the parent of `<td>` (< tr >?) and any CSS connected to that _ Or is the parent just <table> and a plain table row? If you can you provide that we can simulate your code and probably give you an answer

Comment: The classes: container, btn, btn-dark, btn-sm i got it from the documentation of bootstrap i didnt create that all the css i did to that page is the css above and yes the parent is `<tr>` but it doesn't have any css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one, add btn-inline class in your div.

```
<td width="20%"> // you can adjust the width
   <div class="container btn-inline">
...
```

In your css.

```
.btn-inline a{ display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: It didn't work, also tried `btn-inline a{ display: inline-block !important; } ` and didnt work too

Answer (score 0):

Using a flex display should provide the horizontal layout u r looking for...

In bootstrap .. this can be achieved by using the `d-flex` class on the parent element...

```
<td>
    <div class="d-flex">
        <a href="/miembros/{{$item->id_miembro}}/correos" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">Ver</a>
        <a href="/correos/create" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">Agregar</a>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.